# PIC32MZ DA Separate DDR grounding

Tags: microchip, emc, ddr

I am puzzling over the purpose of ferrite beads and grounding on the PIC32MZ DA starter kit.

On page [34 of the User Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005311A.pdf) it shows L2 and L3, and a separate Ground and power net.  It would appear these tie into planes.[image: Starter kit pic]

The real reason for the questions would tend from an EMC standpoint, trying to understand the problem and what this may fix.  Also, I'd like to minimize pcb layers, but don't want to compromize EMC or DDR.

Answer (score 1):

Current flows in complete paths or loops. For best EMI performance, you want to *design* the VDD regions and GND regions, to control the size and shape of the current loops.

Using ferrite beads is the method to separate noisy regions from quiet regions, or from other even more noisy regions. By localizing trash generating circuits where dI/dT is large (amps/nanosecond as inside an MCU), using beads and adequate charge reservoirs (bypass capacitors), the circulating paths are kept almost totally local and the radiated and conducted emissions are minimal. To achieve this, at least use separate VDD regions. To best minimize the circulating paths, separate GND regions also are used, which brings up the challenge of how to route high speed signals and accommodate the need for the accompanying high speed return/GND currents and magnetic-field cancellation.

At that point, slits in planes become the tool, where planes are not totally severed.

After examining the MicronTechnology Application Note PDF, from "DDR3 noise" search, with over 20 capacitors used to achieve low VDD inductance in the face of moderate DD3 currents, I conclude DDR3 is *sensitive* to VDD upsets and ringing. This is consistent with "create a local battery" for the high speed currents, and use separate VDD regions and use GND slits to control the paths used by high speed currents.

Comment: Part of the question is though, is ddr noisy, or sensitive?